# Smoke simulation renders with gaps on fast moving object

Tags: smoke-simulation

I understand that this problem occurs because the "flow" object moves very fast (in 60 frames 72 meters) and a little sideways. But how to fix it? I have tried all possible settings (sampling substeps at maximum, resolution divisions I changed from 50 to 500, tried to change timesteps), but nothing helped.
By the way, I do not need to use this simulation of smoke, so if there are suggestions how to make a beautiful and realistic trace of the missile, with pleasure I will listen. Or if you know exactly how to solve this problem, then please advise values for settings to get a beautiful trace.

The render shows the trace from the first missile and if you look closely, it also shows gaps, but not as obvious as the second.[image]
[image][image][image]